why is the fetch data undefined on the child react component?
i have a useEffect on the parent component that runs a fetch call on render
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCall = async () => {
      try{
          const res = await fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races')
          const data = await res.json()

          setFetchData(prevData => ({
              ...prevData,
              race_list:data.results
          }))
      // console.log('been fetched')
      }catch(err){
          console.error('Error fetching data: ', err)
      }
  }
  fetchCall()
})

then the parent uses an if else statement to determine the content of a div and it looks like this
const decideDiv = (e, divType) => {
  if(divType === 'div_1'){
    return (
      <div>
        <div id='race'>
          <Race functions={{setFetchData:setFetchData,
                          raceFetch: raceFetch,
                          fetchData:fetchData}} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

if i log fetchData to the console in the parent div it logs everything correctly. if i log it in the child component it only renders the initial state.
the parent component
export default function CharCreator () {
    const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState(...someObj)

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCall = async () => {
      try{
          const res = await fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races')
          const data = await res.json()

          setFetchData(prevData => ({
              ...prevData,
              race_list:data.results
          }))
      // console.log('been fetched')
      }catch(err){
          console.error('Error fetching data: ', err)
      }
  }
  fetchCall()
})

  // INITIAL STATE OF THE DIV
const [div, setDiv] = useState(
  <div>
    <button onClick={(e) => {handleNewChar(e, 'class/race')}}>Create Character</button>
  </div>
)

const handleNewChar = (e, newDiv) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)

  if(newDiv === 'class/race'){
    setDiv(
      <div>
        <div id='race_class'>
            <div id='race'>
              <Race functions={{setFetchData:setFetchData,
                              raceFetch: raceFetch,
                              fetchData:fetchData}} />
            </div>
        </div>
    }else if(other logic for other components){
        ...other compoents being rendered
        }
  }

      return(
    <div id='outerParent'>
        <form>
          {div}
            <p>
                <button onClick={logs}>fetchData</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
)
}

the child component
export default function Race({functions}) {

    const {fetchData, raceFetch, setFetchData} = functions

    const [div, setDiv] = useState()

    const isHidden = fetchData?.race?.name ? '' : 'none'

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCall = async () => {
            try{
                const res = await fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races')
                const data = await res.json()
    
                setFetchData(prevData => ({
                    ...prevData,
                    race_list:data.results
                }))
            }catch(err){
                console.error('Error fetching data: ', err)
            }
        }
        fetchCall()
    })

    //ONLY SHOWS THE INITIAL STATE
    console.log('race list', fetchData?.race_list)

    useEffect(() => {
        setDiv(
            <>
                <p> 
                        <select onChange={verifyInput} id='raceSet' defaultValue=''>
                        <option value='' disabled >Select a Race</option>
                        {fetchData?.race_list?.map((race, i) => (
                        <option
                        key={i}
                        data-url={race.url}
                        value={race.name}>
                            {race.name}
                        </option>
                        ))}
                        </select>
                </p>
            </>
        )
    }, [fetchData?.race_list])

    const verifyInput = (e) => {
        const input = e.target.value

        const selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex]
        const url = selected.getAttribute('data-url')
        console.log('url', url)
        
        const compare = fetchData?.race_list?.some(element => element.name === input) || fetchData?.race_list?.some(element => element.name.toLowerCase() === input)

            raceFetch(url)
            setSpawn(prevSpawn => prevSpawn + 1)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                    <h2>Race</h2>
            </div>

            {div}
            
            <div>
                {spawn > 0 ? 
                    <div id='raceInfo'>
                        <RaceInfo functions={{fetchData:fetchData,
                                            setFetchData:setFetchData}} />
                    </div>
                :''}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

there is no 'too many requests' error either
it worked fine when i just all the divs render at the same time, but now that i have it set to only render one at a time it seems that the new state of fetchData is not being sent to the child. i tried moving the fetch call to the child component, but that didnt work either and it still only logs the initial state of fetchData.

you need to post the rest of the code.

I guess you should pass fetchData as a stand alone prop. The your child component should rerender. But yeah please add the whole tow components you need help with.

so, i just added a button on the race component that logs fetchData to the console, and its still only passing the old state as props. on the parent it logs the new state after the fetch call

I dunno if this is the exact issue, but it's standard to pass a callback to the child and set  the useState in the component that holds it, it's possible thats whats caused the no repaint but I wouldnt put that in answer until tested
